# How to edit words in specific paragraph in MSWord using win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I've got a task to edit a serial of MSWord documents. What I   have to do is to change a word in paragraph 3 of each document. I want to use python to finish this job. In the document, there is a table just below paragraph 3.  The problem is that if I change the word of paragraph 3, the paragraph 3 will dispear and the words I filled in will be inside the table below.

My code is

```
import os
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch

w = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word Application')
w.Visible = 1
w.DisplayAlerts = 0
doc = w.Documents.Open(u'F:\\pythonlearning\\a.doc')

doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text = 'Y\n'
```

Comment: Doing `print doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text`  may help diagnose what's going on.

Comment: You are right. I use "for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs" to print all the document, and find out that each paragraph means a carriage return. So if I modify the paragraph(3), first the paragraph(3) 's carriage return would be delete, and then the table below would be paragraph(3), that's what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing probably starts at 0 so use doc.Paragraphs(2) for the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch

w = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word Application')
w.Visible = 1
w.DisplayAlerts = 0
doc = w.Documents.Open(u'F:\\pythonlearning\\a.doc')
doc.Paragraphs(3).Range.InsertBefore ('Y\n')
doc.Paragraphs(4).Range.Text = ''
```

It can work, though not the best way.